# How to restrict accessing initializer method on the class exclusivly

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I am learning blocks In objective-c and re some topics related to pointer or message passing mechanism in objective-c.
As I am reading a question poped-up or occurred to my mind, how one can hide a method from a pointer to , for example, NSString class?? In other words, how to restrict visibility of a method to be only applicable or visible only to the CLASS -NSString-, so that, the instance or the pointer can NOT access it nor see it in the auto-complete?

For my understanding,

```
           init method(s)
```

should be a property for the factory or the main creator/generator to any instance or object of the class, such as NSArray and NSString - [[NSString alloc] init]- however, on creating a pointer to such class, I do have access to

```
           init methods(s)
           [ptr init]
```

Please let me know how to confine accessing the init methods, for example on the class “as if it is a class method”, with the ability to reference it via

```
self
[self init]
```

And to qualify it or precede it with “-“ sign in @interface file ".h" file. Is it possible??

**code**:

```
@interface OwnInterface_v1_0 : NSObject {
   NSString *_country;
 NSString *_city;
    //NSString *_address;
    //NSString *_phone;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *prop;

-(OwnInterface_v1_0 *) initWithCountry: (NSString *) country;
-(OwnInterface_v1_0 *) initWithCity: (NSString *) city;
-(OwnInterface_v1_0 *) initWithCountry: (NSString *) country andCity: (NSString *) city;

-(void) passParameterLessBlock_1:(void (^) (void)) block;

@end
```

Comment: This is exceedingly confusing. What does “how one can hide a method from a pointer to [a] class” mean? What does “how to confine accusing the init methods” mean? What does “how to restrict visibility of a method to be only applicable or visible only to a method” mean? Perhaps this would be clearer if you just showed us example of where you want these methods to be visible and where you’d like them to not be available. I.e., step back and describe the broader problem that you’re trying to solve.

Comment: But, in answer to the broader question of making methods visible or not, the basic idea is that if you want to expose methods, you include them in the `@interface` within the `.h` file. And if you don’t want particular methods to be exposed, you simply omit them from the public `.h` interface.